# JMeter Adding Variables

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I need to add four variables in **JMeter** and store them in another variable that I will be using for a later request (to be stored in the variable finalScore.  I have a `BeanShell PreProcessor` with the following code:

```
overallScore = ${__intSum(${score1}, ${score2}, ${score3}, ${score4}, finalScore)};
```

In executing, I keep getting the following error:

```
2015/10/16 14:05:05 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter:
Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "${score1}"
```

Any ideas on what is wrong and how to resolve?

Answer (score 6):

1. It looks like your `${score1}` variable is not defined
2. You need to remove spaces from __intSum() function, correct syntax is

   ```
   ${__intSum(${score1},${score2},${score3},${score4},finalScore)}
   ```
3. You don't need Beanshell as sum of score1-4 will be stored as `${finalScore}`
   If you need to have a sum of score1-4 **and** finalScore - amend your function as:

   ```
   ${__intSum(${score1},${score2},${score3},${score4},${finalScore},overallScore)}
   ```

References:

- [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) user manual chapter
- [How to Use JMeter Functions - Part III](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) which provides several use cases for __intSum() function

> ${__intSum(1,5,)} - will return 6
>
> ${__intSum(1,5,8)} - will return 14
>
> ${__intSum(1,5,8,SUM)} - will return 14 and store it to SUM variable
>
> ${__intSum(10,-5)} - will return 5
>
> ${__intSum(${A},${B})} - will return an evaluation of A and B variables integer representation sum, which can be handy for Counter value processing.

and extra information on the others.